# How to build a cycle plot in Python Altair?

Tags: python, time-series, visualization, altair, timeserieschart

I'd like to plot the following graph in Altair. Any ideas?

[image]

I have this dataset:

[image]

I've tried

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='Month',
    y='Mean'
)
```

but the output is completely wrong.

[image]

Comment: Your example chart is composed of multiple elements. You cannot achieve the example chart with your code. The example plot is composed of 12 individual plots which are horizontally stacked together. Each plot comprises an area chart and a mean line chart. Try to figure out the individual month chart; after that, you can stack them together to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have the exact dataframe or how you wrangled it, I am assuming the column "Mean" refers to the mean of strike reports in the dataset.

You can create this sort of plot by layering the three graphs:

1. `mark_line` with a point (total strike reports) for each year
2. `mark_area`
3. `mark_line` for the mean (mean of strike reports through the years)

Once we layer the three graphs, we can use `facet` to create multiple graphs for each month.

Following are the steps I had to do to wrangle the data:

```
required = df[(df["Incident Year"] >= "2000") & (df["Incident Year"] <= "2010")] # filter dataset for years between 2000 and 2010

mean_df = required.groupby(by = ["Incident Month", "Incident Year"]).sum().groupby(by = ["Incident Month"]).mean() # to get the mean of the (total strike reports every year) for each month

merged_df = pd.merge(mean_df, new_df, on = "Incident Month") # merge the two dataframes
```

Before wrangling, the data looks like this:

[df before wrangling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juAhl.png)

After wrangling, the data looks something like this:

```
merged_df.head()
```

[df after wrangling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ1Zr.png)

Finally the three graphs can be defined the following way and then layered and faceted:

```
x = alt.Chart(merged_df).mark_line(color = 'darkblue').encode(
    x='Incident Year',
    y=alt.Y('sum(Strikes_x)', title='Number of Strike Reports')
)

y = alt.Chart(merged_df).mark_area(color = 'lightblue').encode(
    x='Incident Year',
    y='sum(Strikes_x)'
)

z = alt.Chart(merged_df).mark_line(color='black').encode(
    x='Incident Year',
    y='Strikes_y'
)
(x+y+z).properties(
    width=50,
    height=300
).facet(column = 'Incident Month')
```

Finally the graph looks something like this:

[image]

Hope this helped!